# Swipe left not working for view pager in android espresso

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-espresso

I have implemented a `ViewPager` in my android application. When I make test case in espresso to swipe the viewPager,it does not swipe to next view page.

```
onView(withId(R.id.customviewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
```

This code is working for some view pages but not for all.
As some view pages have High resolution image in which swipe is not working.

Comment: I don't think the high resolution of an image would cause the ViewPager to be unswipeable. What sort of resolution are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a custom swipe event where you exactly define from where to where the swipe is performed:

```
public static ViewAction customLeftSwipe() {
return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_LEFT, Press.FINGER);
```

}
usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id. customviewpager)).perform(customLeftSwipe());
```

This way you can change the swipe event and where it should happen and how fast. Alternatively, in case you display the viewpager tabs you could select them and click them directly (without swiping).

Comment: Not working @stamanuel. The swipe not working for high resolution images.

Comment: You may have to check with dev or see if you know the actual if swipe is implement on that page correctly, Pleace check this lik: http://www.android-examples.com/android-swipe-gesture-detector-code-example-tutorial/